# Factorization "$(a -1)(b -1)$"

Tags: factoring

I need to factorize $ab -a -b +1$. 
I know that the answer is $(a -1)(b -1)$ can anyone give me some tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

$ab-a-b+1=a(b-1)-(b-1)=a(b-1)-1(b-1)=(a-1)(b-1)$

Comment: wow, thanks very much, I didn't saw "-b +1= -1(b-1)"

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the distributive law twice: 
\begin{align*}
ab - a - b +1 = a(b-1) - (b-1) = (a-1)(b-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks I didn't saw "-b +1 = -1(b -1)"